# Link to form with Button selected as primary

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to link to a page on a different site that contains three buttons in a form. When I link to the page xyz.com/form , by default the 'Highlighted' button is checked since it contains the btn-primary class. How can I create a link from my site linking to xyz.com/form with the btn-primary class selected for 'Link One' or 'Link Two' rather than 'Highlighted'?

```
<form>
<div class="col-xs-12">
<a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-primary">Highlighted</a>
<a class="btn btn-block btn-default">Link One</a>
<a class="btn btn-block btn-default">Link Two</a>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: If you have access to `xyz.com/form` then you can implement this on both sites. Otherwise it isn't possible

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

It isn't possible to make arbitrary changes to the HTML of an arbitrary site through the URL.

(If it was, you could watch as I linked to your bank's online banking service with a link that changed their login form to point to my own, malicious, site).

You would have to make the changes on the site hosting the HTML you want to change.

Ideally, you would create different pages representing each version of the page. You could do this dynamically using server-side code which (for instance) paid attention to the query string.

You could also use JavaScript (in the page) to examine the URL and modify the DOM based on it.